# How to set custom font in whole Vaadin 7 application

Tags: css, fonts, vaadin, vaadin7

I defined custom font for my application because by default characters like 'č' did render with Arial font while rest of application rendered with "Open Sans Light". In `styles.scss`:

```
@include v-font('LocalFont', '../../../../mytheme/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-ext_latin-300');
...
...
```

From rendered webpage I see font family used depends on `styles.css`:

```
.mytheme.v-app, .mytheme.v-app-loading {
  font: 300 16px/1.55 "Open Sans", sans-serif;
```

but I see no way affecting it. In `mytheme.scss` within `@mixin mytheme {` I tried to define:

```
.v-app, .v-app-loading {
    font: 300 16px/1.55 LocalFont, sans-serif;
}

.mytheme.v-app, .mytheme.v-app-loading {
    font: 300 16px/1.55 LocalFont, sans-serif;
}
```

but in `styles.css` it is build as:

```
.mytheme .v-app, .mytheme .v-app-loading {
  font: 300 16px/1.55 LocalFont, sans-serif;
}

.mytheme .mytheme.v-app, .mytheme .mytheme.v-app-loading {
  font: 300 16px/1.55 LocalFont, sans-serif;
}
```

and that will not use my local fonts (unless I remove spaces after .mytheme).

**Is there a way to affect font family in `.mytheme.v-app, .mytheme.v-app-loading {`?**

As a workaround I defined this in my theme:

```
.v-ui{
    font: 300 16px/1.55 LocalFont, sans-serif;
}

.v-tooltip{
    font: 300 16px/1.55 LocalFont, sans-serif;
}

.v-window{
    font: 300 16px/1.55 LocalFont, sans-serif;
}

.v-Notification{
    font: 300 16px/1.55 LocalFont, sans-serif;
}
```

This covers probably all cases, but I am not sure if vaadin could add element  that is direct child of element with `v-app` css class and uses other css class. **Is this workaround applying to all cases - does vaadin use other css classes that are direct child of `v-app` class?**

Notes:

[Vaadin documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/themes/themes-fonts.html) only states to use font family in my styles.

I am using server fonts because application is behind proxy and using web fonts for rendering characters like 'č' fails because some clients have no access outside application server.

Initally I tried to define my fonts in `styles.scss` like:

```
@include v-font('Open Sans', '../../../../mytheme/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-ext_latin-300');
...
@include v-font('Open Sans Light', '../../../../mytheme/fonts/open-sans-v15-latin-ext_latin-300');
...
```

But it did not used my fonts for rendering 'č', not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So.. if you've called your theme: **my-theme**

In the file: **my-theme.scss**

You need to add at the top the file: `$v-font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;`

[Here's a link to the other Valo Theme variables](https://vaadin.com/api/valo/)

Comment: As I use `LocalFont`, `$v-font-family: LocalFont, sans-serif;` worked

Comment: @Piro Glad to be able to help. I've added a link to a page with other Valo Theme variables that might be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

This Question is about the older version 7 of Vaadin. Here's an Answer for those with the same need in current Vaadin 14.

## Vaadin Flow

The newer generation of Vaadin version 10 and later is known as *Flow*. This revamp of Vaadin now uses the [Lumo theme](https://cdn.vaadin.com/vaadin-lumo-styles/1.5.0/demo/) by default. The theme is designed to be easy to alter, changing font, size, color, spacing, and so on.

The Vaadin team now [offers an online editor](https://demo.vaadin.com/lumo-editor/) to make changing the theme easy, with a palette of settings to tweak, and a visual display to see the effects. When you are satisfied, you can download the theme settings for use in your Vaadin project.

In particular, on the *Typography* tab with its *Font family* pop-up menu, you can choose a default font for the entire app. For finer control of your [Web typography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_typography), you can open the *Advanced* section to edit the [CSS font stack](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/system-font-stack/).

By the way, Lumo has both a light and a dark mode, the dark shown here.

[image]